# Check if document key/id exists with Tire

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire, retire

I am using Tire gem as an elasticsearch client.

I wanted to know if there is a way to know if the document with known id exists in the index?

something like:

```
 Tire.exists? { index: 'myIndex', type: 'myType', id: 'myId' }
```

Comment: i think there is no such thing for documents. i thought there was a simple get(id) but i can't find it any longer...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
Tire::Configuration.client.get "#{Tire::Configuration.url}/myindex/mytype/myid?pretty"
```

If the document exists then returns the document with indexed properties or else the response body contains

```
{
  "exists" : false
}
```